# is there way to find which docker image is using current gpu?

Tags: docker, gpu

I figure that sometimes when I using the `gpu` on docker image it holds the gpu memory when it not using it, but I can not find **which docker image is holding the gpu**.

Let say I want to know docker image `x` is using gpu `2`

is there way to get this information? (`pid`?)

Answer (score 2):

This should work on Linux command line.

Suppose your gpu `2` is a nvidia. In linux, all devices are located in the `/dev` directory, so your gpu can be identified in the filesystem by something like this, `/dev/nvidia1`. You can identify the processes using it with the command `fuser`, like this

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia1
```

This will return the PID of all processes using your gpu.
Then, check the processes running in the host with command `ps` and then filter it using command `grep`

```
ps -e -o pid,comm,cgroup | grep docker
```

This will return PID, command name, and cgroup to which process belong. The cgroup output contain the full container id, which you can match against `docker ps -a` to find out exactly which docker image is using the gpu.

Probably there is a better way to do it, but for now it might help.